# Getting year, quarter from orderDate SQL

Tags: sql, adventureworks

I am working with adventureworks 2019 and want to forecast using the sales revenue data.  Currently, the data is categorised into salesOrders (so SalesOrderID, just not selected in this query).  Hence why there are many rows for the same quarter in the same year.

I am using the current query:

```
SELECT
SST.[Name] AS RegionName,
CASE WHEN SSOH.[OnlineOrderFlag] = 1 THEN 'Online' ELSE 'Reseller' END AS [SalesChannel],
YEAR(SSOH.[OrderDate]) AS Year,
DATEPART(Quarter, SSOH.[OrderDate]) AS Quarter,
SSOD.[LineTotal] AS Revenue


FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] AS SSOD
LEFT JOIN [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] AS SSOH
ON SSOD.[SalesOrderID] = SSOH.[SalesOrderID]
LEFT JOIN [Production].[Product] AS PP
ON SSOD.[ProductID] = PP.[ProductID]
LEFT JOIN [Sales].[SalesTerritory] AS SST
ON SST.TerritoryID = SSOH.TerritoryID
```

and getting output:

```
RegionName  SalesChannel    Year    Quarter Revenue
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   2024.994000
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   6074.982000
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   2024.994000
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   2039.994000
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   2039.994000
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   4079.988000
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   2039.994000
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   86.521200
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   28.840400
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   34.200000
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   10.373000
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   80.746000
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   419.458900
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   874.794000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   809.760000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   714.704300
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1429.408600
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   20.746000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   115.361600
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1445.189800
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   6074.982000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   4049.988000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   40.373000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1637.400000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   8099.976000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   4079.988000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   57.680800
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   4049.988000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   100.932500
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1258.376700
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   2097.294500
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   367.876400
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   3499.176000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   551.814600
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   2097.294500
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1258.376700
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   838.917800
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   2146.962000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   874.794000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1258.376700
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   356.898000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   5248.764000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   183.938200
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   535.742400
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   2146.962000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1258.376700
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   183.938200
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   356.898000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   178.580800
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1258.376700
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   874.794000
Southwest   Reseller    2011    2   419.458900
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   2039.994000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   8099.976000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   28.840400
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   28.840400
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   4049.988000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   6119.982000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   2039.994000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   2024.994000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   40.373000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   2039.994000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   20.186500
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   57.680800
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   4049.988000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   10.373000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   4049.988000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   2024.994000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   34.200000
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   2024.994000
Southwest   Reseller    2011    2   419.458900
Southwest   Reseller    2011    2   2146.962000
Southwest   Reseller    2011    2   356.898000
Southwest   Reseller    2011    2   874.794000
Southwest   Reseller    2011    2   838.917800
Southwest   Reseller    2011    2   419.458900
Central Reseller    2011    2   17.100000
Central Reseller    2011    2   2039.994000
Central Reseller    2011    2   2024.994000
Central Reseller    2011    2   2024.994000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   2624.382000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   4293.924000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   2936.212300
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   2516.753400
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   173.042400
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1103.629200
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   40.373000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   40.373000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1749.588000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   20.746000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   367.876400
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   2624.382000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1258.376700
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   838.917800
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   551.814600
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   838.917800
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   838.917800
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   367.876400
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   28.840400
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   838.917800
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1427.592000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   5248.764000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1677.835600
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   535.742400
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   115.361600
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   535.742400
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   20.186500
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1070.694000
Canada  Reseller    2011    2   1258.376700
Northwest   Reseller    2011    2   714.704300
```

I am trying to add all of the revenue for each quarter in each year to get (imagine in the revenue column is one value for say year 2011, quarter 1:

```
RegionName  SalesChannel    Year    Quarter Revenue
Southeast   Reseller    2011    1   
Southeast   Reseller    2011    2   
Southeast   Reseller    2011    3   
Southeast   Reseller    2011    4  
Southeast   Reseller    2012    1   
Southeast   Reseller    2012    2  
Southeast   Reseller    2012    3
```

I have used:

```
WHERE SST.[Name] = 'Australia' AND SSOH.[OnlineOrderFlag] = 1

GROUP BY DATEPART(Quarter, SSOH.[OrderDate]), SST.[Name], SSOH.[OnlineOrderFlag], SSOH.[OrderDate], SSOD.[LineTotal]
```

to get where region is only Australia, and sales channel is 'online', however I get an output like this:

```
RegionName  SalesChannel    Year    Quarter Revenue
Australia   Online  2012    1   3578.270000
Australia   Online  2012    1   3578.270000
Australia   Online  2012    1   3578.270000
Australia   Online  2012    1   3578.270000
Australia   Online  2012    1   3399.990000
Australia   Online  2012    1   3578.270000
Australia   Online  2012    1   3578.270000
Australia   Online  2012    1   3399.990000
Australia   Online  2012    1   3578.270000
Australia   Online  2012    1   3578.270000
Australia   Online  2012    1   3578.270000
```

so, it is still not grouping the revenue by quarter like I want it to.

Does anyone know a way to solve this?

It would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want aggregation:

```
SELECT SST.[Name] AS RegionName,
       (CASE WHEN SSOH.[OnlineOrderFlag] = 1 THEN 'Online' ELSE 'Reseller'
        END) AS [SalesChannel],
       YEAR(SSOH.[OrderDate]) AS Year,
       DATEPART(Quarter, SSOH.[OrderDate]) AS Quarter,
       SUM(SSOD.[LineTotal]) AS Revenue
FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] SSOD LEFT JOIN
     [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] SSOH
     ON SSOD.[SalesOrderID] = SSOH.[SalesOrderID] LEFT JOIN
     [Production].[Product] AS PP
     ON SSOD.[ProductID] = PP.[ProductID] LEFT JOIN
     [Sales].[SalesTerritory] AS SST
     ON SST.TerritoryID = SSOH.TerritoryID
GROUP BY SST.[Name] AS RegionName,
         (CASE WHEN SSOH.[OnlineOrderFlag] = 1 THEN 'Online' ELSE 'Reseller'
          END) AS [SalesChannel],
         YEAR(SSOH.[OrderDate]) AS Year,
         DATEPART(Quarter, SSOH.[OrderDate]);
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the input.  I had to change a few things (they were very minor), but it worked perfectly.  I assume you did not have the database to hand to crosscheck it.

Comment: @Archnem . . . No, I do not.